# Text is not showing in uitextview

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, uitextview

I have added a textview on uiview. and when i am trying to enter data into it then its not showing.

Following in my code

```
questionView1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 40, 260, 350)];
[questionView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
quesText1 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 240, 270)];
quesText1.layer.borderWidth = 10.0f;
[quesText1 setText:@"Everything Ok"];
quesText1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
quesText1.tag = 100;
quesText1.delegate = self;
[questionView1 addSubview:quesText1];
```

its showing the default text but tryinng to enter data through keyboard then its not showing.

However, when i checked in its delegate(below) then its printing the correct value

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView;{
    NSLog(@"%@",textView.text);\\ print correct value but value not showing in        uitextview area.
}
```

Dnt know how and why its happening.. anyone knows?

Comment: I used your code and it is working perfectly in my simulator.

Answer (score 1):

once check this one ,

```
UIView*   questionView1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 40, 260, 350)];
    [questionView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
   UITextView* quesText1 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 270)];
    quesText1.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0);
    quesText1.layer.borderWidth = 10.0f;
    quesText1.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [quesText1 setText:@"Everything Ok"];
    quesText1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    quesText1.tag = 100;
    quesText1.delegate = self;
    [questionView1 addSubview:quesText1];
    [self.view addSubview:questionView1];
    questionView1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

set this line  in your code

```
    quesText1.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Things to try out

1. Your background color is black and the textcolor will be black by
   default.So set text color to white
2. The problem may be setting the border such that it covers the
   default text

Comment: This was my problem, so ensure that the text color is set after the text is.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

step1:

```
[self.view addSubView:questionView1];
```

step2:

adopt the protocol `'UITextViewDelegate'` in your .h file and also put the following code

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text

{

    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {

        [textView resignFirstResponder];

    }
        return YES;
}
```